# Can you prevent Angular requests within dynamic innerhtml?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, innerhtml

I have an element like so:

```
<div [innerHtml]="htmlContent | sanitiseHtml"></div>
```

Where the sanatiseHtml pipe simply sanatises the html.

If this htmlContent contains relative images these requests fail with a 404 (it's not my content).

Is there any way to block some html from making these requests without running through the string and removing them?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to write your own pipe with custom logic to check for the relative path to images.

See section Custom Pipes here https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: Hopefully not, I fear so though. If no-one knows a way "without running through the string and removing them" I'll mark as correct